# Getting sample/slice of a dictionary, the first X amount of keys

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to display the first 10 or so keys of an object

```
{
"key1": "val",
"key2": "val",
"key3": "val",
... etc
}
```

I'm trying myDict.slice(0, 3) but that doesn't work. More specifically I'm using VueJS to output this

```
<span v-for="val, key in someDictionary">{{ key }}</span>
```

My dictionary could have 100s of keys, but for now I just want to initially load a given amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `slice` the array you get from `Object.entries` and then build a new object with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) (but keep in mind that `Object.fromEntries` is only supported in ES2019):

```js
const data = {
  "key1": "val1",
  "key2": "val2",
  "key3": "val3",
  "key4": "val4",
  "key5": "val5",
  "key6": "val6",
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).slice(0, 3));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method is only avalible on the Array type, and is not avalible on a plain object.

To achieve what you require, you could extract the key/value entries of your input object with [`Object#entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the reduce the first "n" number of entries to the reduced to the result.

In code that could be expressed as:

```js
const obj = {
"key1": "val1",
"key2": "val2",
"key3": "val3",
"key4": "val4",
"key5": "val5",
"key6": "val6",
"key7": "val7"
};

const includeCount = 3;

const res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value], index) => 
  // Accumulate current entry [key/value] to result object (acc) if
  // index before includeCount, otherwise just return result object
  ((index < includeCount) ? { ...acc, [key] : value } : acc), 
  {});

console.log(res);
```